# Gurobi Python "Either or" constraint

Tags: python, optimization, jupyter-notebook, gurobi

I am creating an optimization model in Gurobi and want to add two constraints, of which only one has to be fulfilled. So either A or B, both together are impossible.

My idea was to add binary variables and create the following:

```
    if A:
       binary=1
    elif B:
       binary=1
    else:
       binary=0
```

And then I wanted to use

```
 m.addConstr(binary>=1)
```

but apparently that's an unsupported operand type for 'bool' and 'Nonetype'.
Does anyone know to solve this problem?

Comment: I know nothing about what gurobi, but you're looking for XOR, which is logically equivalent to `(A & !B) | (!A & B)`, maybe that will help

Comment: I don't think I need to use XOR to prevent A & B from happening, because A & B are equations that can't be fulfilled at the same time anyway.
My main problem is that i can't get the constraint to work.
Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Oh, misread "both together are impossible". (Also: edit in the stack trace of the error to make your question easier to answer)

Comment: Usually (let's assume OR here, instead of XOR; there are linearizations for XOR) this is done using two indicator-constraints producing two new binary-variables and calculating an or (b0 + b1 >= 1) over these. It seems gurobi now introduced some wrappers to do most of that automatically: [General constraints](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/constraints.html). More help is not possible, as there is no real code here to work with.